# Deploy Google App Engine backend from Android Studio

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

Is it possible to deploy a Google App Engine backend module in Android Studio as a Google App Engine project (on Google's servers)? In eclipse this was possible with the plugin, but now I don't see how to do this or found someone else doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see what's under the hood of gradle:

```
gradlew tasks
```

If you want only the .war file

```
gradlew war
```

Will do the job:

```
gradlew appengineUpdate
```

Comment: Someone reading this may find this useful: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

Comment: @RyanHeitner or without starting digging in the manual, you can just use the gradlew tasks which more or less makes displays a list of 2-tuples 'command' 'meaningful description'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from UI itself. Go to

```
Build -> Deploy Module to App Engine
```

[image]

[image]

If you are deploying this for the 1st time then you will have to sign in to your google account by using add account button.

[image]

Comment: I think that was not possible at the time of asking the question. AndroidStudio was still in beta. ;)

Comment: Well I landed on this question searching for same.. so hoping it will help others too :). It took me time to figure out how to  sign in from Studio.