# Mobile Backend Starter Java - on Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio

Has anyone managed to extend "Mobile Backend Starter Java"  on Android Studio
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java

Frustratingly any documentation that exists seems out of date or only for Eclipse".

I want to use Gradle and not Maven , Android Studio and not Eclipse

I followed the Tutorial
https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/

but the extend page left me confused
https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/extend_backend

I would like to know if anyone has tried this

---

I thought about going from the other direction creating an app and then *Google Cloud Tools* and *App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging* but I do not see a deploy , I did see this, [Deploy Google App Engine backend from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995240/deploy-google-app-engine-backend-from-android-studio)
but have not tried yet

Comment: Did you ever get any further? I'm trying to use the Backend on an existing app and have trouble integrating it into my source code.

Comment: I moved my backend to parse.com I got frustrated with the dearth of up to date documentation from Google.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project on GitHub which you can use as module. It provides you with the basic client libraries. You can use it as starting point. See https://github.com/thagikura/mobile-backend-starter-android-client-with-AndroidStudio and follow the instructions there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will investigate get back to this